# Create fragment and asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hi guys i have a big problem...
i have two asynctask...

arrivi.java:

```
    public class arrivi extends Fragment implements InterfaceTaskFinished{
    ListView list;
    int thread = 0;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public String[] lista = new String[200];
    public String[] Compagnia = new String[200];
    public String[] CodiceVolo = new String[200];
    public String[] Citta = new String[200];
    public String[] OraPrevista = new String[200];
    public String[] OraStimata = new String[200];
    public String[] StatoVolo = new String[200];


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View arrivi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 

          new Arrivi(this).execute();
       // new partenze().new Partenze().execute();

       return arrivi;
    }

    public class Arrivi extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
    //    String info;
        boolean result;
        private final InterfaceTaskFinished listener;

        public Arrivi(InterfaceTaskFinished listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            prog.setMessage("Connessione in corso...");
            prog.show();
            prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            prog.setCancelable(false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {           
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://s.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();

                org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").first();
                Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();

                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    thread++;

                    Compagnia[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    CodiceVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    Citta[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    OraPrevista[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    OraStimata[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    StatoVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                    System.out.println(StatoVolo[thread]);
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) { 
             if(!result) {
                 return;
             }

             if(listener != null) {
                 prog.dismiss();
               CheckRow();

                 listener.onTaskFinished();
             }
         }


    }// FINE THREAD 

    public void CheckRow(){

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++) {

            RowItem item = new RowItem(Compagnia[i], CodiceVolo[i], Citta[i],OraPrevista[i],  OraStimata[i], StatoVolo[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        } 
        list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskFinished() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new partenze();
            new partenze().new Partenze().execute();
    }
}
```

partenze.java:

```
    public class partenze extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    int thread = 0;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public String[] lista = new String[200];
    public String[] Compagnia = new String[200];
    public String[] CodiceVolo = new String[200];
    public String[] Citta = new String[200];
    public String[] OraPrevista = new String[200];
    public String[] OraStimata = new String[200];
    public String[] StatoVolo = new String[200];

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View partenze = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partenze, container, false);
      // new Partenze().execute("");
          return partenze;
   }

   public class Partenze extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       ProgressDialog prog;
       String info;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {       
               org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://s.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();

               org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").get(1);
               Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();


               while(iterator.hasNext()){ 
                   thread++;

                   Compagnia[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                   CodiceVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                   Citta[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                   OraPrevista[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                   OraStimata[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                   StatoVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
               }
        }catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }return info;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
           super.onPostExecute(result);
         //  prog.dismiss();

           CheckRow();
       }
   }// FINE THREAD 


   public void CheckRow(){

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
       for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++) {

           RowItem item = new RowItem(Compagnia[i], CodiceVolo[i], Citta[i],OraPrevista[i],  OraStimata[i], StatoVolo[i]);
           rowItems.add(item);
       } 
       list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView2);
       CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);


   }
}
```

the error is:

```
04-22 19:19:20.860: E/AndroidRuntime(23765):    at com.gianni.app.partenze.CheckRow(partenze.java:92)
```

it is uguale to:

```
   list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

i need to create befor the wiew... there is a solution for execute befor the second thread

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View partenze = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partenze, container, false);
          return partenze;
   }
```

????
and later doInBackground...etc...
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is VERY unclear, but i will take a stab at what you are trying to do.

If you really need to do multiple tasks like this, you really should be using a `Service` to handle these in the background, especially since you have some crossover code.

If you have tasks that need to complete in their own thread, but orderly you should consider spinning new Runnable threads and then creating a situation where the next cannot be started without being spun by the other thread, which then closes itself.

To Spin new thread:

```
new Thread(new ConnectThread()).start();
```

Class of Runnable thread:

```
class ConnectThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                   //Do Stuff 
                   if(finish){ 
                       //stop the thread and start the other passing variables
                       //Use this to stop the thread
                       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    } 
}
```

`AsyncTask` should really only be used when you need information that only that Activity needs and it also eats up resources that the one Activity could use. It is easier and higher performance to use a general purpose `Service` class to handle hand-over.

Does this help?

Comment: i want run  onCreateView(....) in partenze.java why i execute  partenze asynctask thread in arrivi.java (separate class) but for execute the baseadapter i need to lunch OnCreateView...

Comment: By the way, AsyncTask is fine for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
04-22 19:19:20.860: E/AndroidRuntime(23765):    at com.gianni.app.partenze.CheckRow(partenze.java:92)
```

That is only one line in the log output which tells you part of where the error occurs, but not what actually happened. You need to show more of the stack trace.

```
list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

Change this to call

```
list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

If that doesn't work, there may be something wrong with your XML (maybe it's not returning a list view). Post the XML.

Comment: i want run  onCreateView(....) in partenze.java why i execute  partenze asynctask thread in arrivi.java (separate class) but for execute the baseadapter i need to lunch OnCreateView...

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. One bit of confusion is your class names. partenze and Partenze, for example, are very similar. You might want to change these to PartenzeFragment and PartenzeTask, for clarity. Are you saying you want to create the Arrivi task from the Partenze fragment? If so you will need to restructure. You might refactor PartenzeTask out into its own file, and then give it a parameter when creating the task to indicate which UI (which fragment) to update when finished.

Comment: Ok sorry... when i execute in arrivi.java the partenze thread; i get an error why UI is not created. Is possible  before create the UI partenze with and after continue the execution thread? If you look in arrivi.java there is the partenze thread. Thank you!

Comment: When you wrote "new partenze().new Partenze().execute();" you seem to be creating a fragment for the purpose of executing the task, but it is unattached to any UI. The task Partenze is an inner class of the fragment partenze, so if you want to use it without a partenze, you should refactor it into its own separate class.

Comment: Also the fact that the fragment partenze is unattached to any UI explains why findViewById() doesn't work on it. onCreateView for that instance has never been called. You're going to have to restructure your code.

Comment: Yes...if i call partenze thread in partenze.java its works fine... but i want execute partenze thread in arrivi.java.. can you help me? If i want execute partenze thread in arrivi.java i need to lunch before oncreateView() why view isn' created..